# How to re-render checkbox state when mapping over state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-state

I have a component where I can select several checkboxes. For each selected checkbox, a chip is generated that illustrates the selected checkboxes. These chips have a remove handler that can remove the selections (like the checkbox itself9. This works so far, but if I use the chips to remove the selection, the state of the corresponding checkbox is not adjusted.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the rendering of my checkboxes (simplified):**

```
  {filteredData(data)?.map((data, index) => (
    <CheckBox
     // some other props
     selected={selected.includes(data.id)}
     onChange={() => handleState(data.id)}
    />
  ))}
```

**Here is the rendering of my chips:**

```
{selected.map((checkbox) => (
  <Chip
    onDelete={() => handleState(checkbox.id, true)}
  />
 ))}
```

**Here is the handler method:**

```
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleState = (id: string, withC?: boolean): void => {
    const selectedCB = [...selected];
    const index = selectedCB.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);

    if (index > -1 || withC) {
      selectedCB.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      selectedCB.push(data.find((item) => item.id === id));
    }
    setSelected(selectedCB);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the issue with the checkbox `selected` condition. The following line:

```
     selected={selected.includes(data.id)}
```

Notice that `selected` is an array of object, so checking `includes()` with `data.id` will not work. Replace your selected logic with

```
     selected={selected.find(cb => cb.id === data.id)
```

It should work!

Comment: Thanks, it works :) - selected.includes(data) works as well. The id is not needed here.